# Google DOCS - App script - Convert / Search and replace a date format from YYYY-MM-DD to DD/MM/YYYY

Tags: date, google-apps-script, search, format, google-docs

If changing date formats is something we use to do in Sheets quite often and is quite common to implement in scripts, what about google DOCS ?

There is a App script link in google DOCS and I tried to code something...but... where to start from ? I lost my orientation when it comes to do something for google DOCS.

How could I search inside a document for dates in this format ####-##-## (YYYY-MM-DD) and replace it by ##/##/#### (DD/MM/YYYY) ?
I know how to do it in Sheets. But Docs ?

No idea !

I don't even know if it's possible :D

Here is a sample Hi it's about searching a whole document of several pages, find dates that are in "YYYY-MM-DD format and change them into DD/MM/YYYY.

Here is the sample document in order to illustrate what I'm searching to do : https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N9JMTRSI5zGVZSOUh5GurwSEZLsK0bvHetH4YQ_LetE/edit

In fact I would like to replace
(\d{4})-(\d*)-\d*
by
\d*/(\d*)/(\d{4})
in the whole text

Will you be able to help me ?

Comment: Regex⠀‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀

Comment: @pedegasc, Are you searching for specific dates or all the dates in the document with format  (YYYY-MM-DD) and replacing it with  (DD/MM/YYYY)? Do you have a sample doc?

Comment: Hi it's about searching a whole document of several pages, find dates that are in "YYYY-MM-DD format and change them into DD/MM/YYYY. Here is a sample https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N9JMTRSI5zGVZSOUh5GurwSEZLsK0bvHetH4YQ_LetE/edit

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of replacing dates YYYY-MM-DD to DD-MM-YYYY.  I simply run from script editor but it could be linked to menu option or button.

Note however, month and day have to be in the form of 2 digits 01 for January, 01 for the first day of the month.

```
function convertDates() {
  try {
    let doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    let body = doc.getBody();
    let found = body.findText("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}");
    let date1 = null;
    while( found ) {
      let text = found.getElement().asText();
      if( found.isPartial() ) {
        let start = found.getStartOffset();
        let end = found.getEndOffsetInclusive();
        date1 = text.getText().substring(start,end+1);
      }
      else {
        date1 = text.getText();
      }
      let date2 = date1.split("-");
      date2 = date2[2]+'/'+date2[1]+'/'+date2[0];
      text.replaceText(date1,date2);
      found = body.findText("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}",found);
    }
  }
  catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Reference

- [DocumentApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/document-app)
- [Body.findText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/body#findText(String))
- [Text.replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#replaceText(String,String))
- [Regexr for testing](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have several problems. First one is execution too long therefore no changes. And the other test I made, the whole text was changed into undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/undefined/

Comment: This is the document I'm testing it on: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1N9JMTRSI5zGVZSOUh5GurwSEZLsK0bvHetH4YQ_LetE/edit

Comment: I've edited the regex expression to search only for dates of the form YYYY-MM-DD.  The previous regex would find any long number.

Answer (score 0):

```
function myfunk() {
  let r = DocumentApp.getUi().prompt("Enter 4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit date", "yyyy/MM/dd", DocumentApp.getUi().ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if (r.getSelectedButton() == DocumentApp.getUi().Button.OK) {
    let t = r.getResponseText().split("\/");
    let d = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(t[0], Number(t[1] - 1), t[2]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "dd/MM/yyyy");
    DocumentApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(d),"dd/MM/yyyy");
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and allow me to apologise as I made you work hard, and I obviously made a bad description of my problematic. 
It was about searching throughout the whole text on several pages, to find dates in the YYYY-MM-DD format and convert them into DD/MM/YYYY. I hope it did not take you too long, thanks for your help !